# Python best module import practise

Tags: python, module, python-import

I have a python module mymodule.py:

```
def auth():
    '''Authorize and generate a JSON file'''
    return j

j = auth()

def get_value(key):
    '''Takes the key and return value from JSON'''
    value = j[key]
    return value
```

I have a program where I use this module myprogram.py:

```
import mymodule
keys = [1,2,3,4,5]

def simple_program(keys):
    # mymodule.auth() should I place it here?
    for key in keys:
        value = mymodule.get_value(key)
        return value
```

So the goal is to call mymodule.auth() once, every time I run simple_program to refresh the JSON file. I don't know how to achieve this. Because myprogram.py is also a module and I call simple_program() from another .py file. So where do I place mymodule.auth()? Is it ok to place mymodule.auth() inside simple_program?

Comment: It looks like you are already calling `auth()` in `mymodule`.

Answer (score 0):

The instant you import mymodule the code below runs

```
j = auth()
```

which is why when you call `mymodule.get_value()` it works.  This causes J to be a singleton in the global space. Everytime you import this, `auth()` will run again.  This could be bad.

What you could do is this:

```
def auth():
    '''Authorize and generate a JSON file'''
    return j

j = None

def get_value(key):
    global j
    '''Takes the key and return value from JSON'''
    if not j:
        j = auth()
    value = j[key]
    return value
```

Now you just need to run `get_value()` and everything should work fine.  No need to execute `auth()` again.

Answer (score 0):

Your exact use case is a little vague (e.g. simple_program is not the main program but smth like a subroutine? and it is called several times from another py file?), but it seems to me like you should get familiar with classes. I would suggest to implement `auth()` as a class, e.g. like this:

```
class MyJson(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._json = ... # do authorization and generation here and save the result as member

  def get_value(self, key):
    value = self._json[key]
    return value
```

Now import and create an object of that class wherever you need it for the first time

```
from mymodule import MyJson
# ...
my_json = MyJson()
```

If you only need it to be initialized once, do that in your main program and pass the `my_json` object as parameter to `simple_program` (which should possibly also be a class). And then use it like

```
value = my_json.get_value(key)
```